# Spring PUT Request: Unsupported Media Type (Code: 415)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have got a rather obscure issue which I am not able to figure out after days of debugging. The issue is one of our PUT REST API started throwing `Unsupported Media type` in production. Here is the definition of method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/put/user/profile", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String updateProfile(@RequestBody UserAndroid user, ModelMap model,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    }
```

In the PUT request, we are just passing the mobile number as follows:

```
{ "mobile": "9999559848"}
```

Here is the UserAndroid entity:

https://gist.github.com/madhur/eb0d9d006f4e4da706d7

Now, the most surprising part. After tracing down the github commits, we traced down the error to this newly introduced field in `User` (not the `UserAndroid`. they are different but related) entity (https://gist.github.com/madhur/06bbcfe11c0e751ab4df) :

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private FullContactDetails fullContactDetails;
```

If we remove this field, the API starts working fine. Can anyone enlighten me why is this happening?

Update: Here are the Spring MVC logs upon executing the request:

https://gist.github.com/madhur/ef357f614b18c6ed42cb

Using Spring 3.2.2. Yes, we have both gson-2.2.4.jar and jackson in classpath.

```
24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@6427300a] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@47672d99] to thread [http-bio-8080-exec-3]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsRequestWrapper@5927198c
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc' processing PUT request for [/mobileapp/v1/put/user/profile.json]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@3bf55f38] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc'
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /mobileapp/v1/put/user/profile.json
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Found 1 matching mapping(s) for [/mobileapp/v1/put/user/profile.json] : [{[/mobileapp/v1/put/user/profile.*],methods=[PUT],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.lsa.akosha.webservices.MobileAppServiceController.updateProfile(com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mobileAppServiceController'
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@439ee876]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@6427300a] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@47672d99] bound to thread [http-bio-8080-exec-3]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy - Connecting to database for operation 'prepareStatement'
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy - Using existing database connection for operation 'isClosed'
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy - Using existing database connection for operation 'getAutoCommit'
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy - Using existing database connection for operation 'isClosed'
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy - Using existing database connection for operation 'getWarnings'
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy - Using existing database connection for operation 'clearWarnings'
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy - Using existing database connection for operation 'close'
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver@18d649bf] supports [class com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver@3d9c4ab3] supports [class com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver@5fec4d5e] supports [class com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.PathVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver@7bd9d9bd] supports [class com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MatrixVariableMethodArgumentResolver@1b6646d1] supports [class com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MatrixVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver@426f839b] supports [class com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor@27295730] supports [class com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor@b1b2466] supports [class com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod - Error resolving argument [0] [type=com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid]
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [com.lsa.akosha.webservices.MobileAppServiceController]
Method [public java.lang.String com.lsa.akosha.webservices.MobileAppServiceController.updateProfile(com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]

 org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:849)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:649)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.lsa.akosha.webservices.MobileAppServiceController.updateProfile(com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.lsa.akosha.webservices.MobileAppServiceController.updateProfile(com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.lsa.akosha.webservices.MobileAppServiceController.updateProfile(com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.lsa.akosha.webservices.MobileAppServiceController.updateProfile(com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.lsa.akosha.webservices.MobileAppServiceController.updateProfile(com.lsa.akosha.entity.UserAndroid,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsRequestWrapper@5927198c
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/mobileapp/v1/put/user/profile.json]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[PUT]; servlet=[mvc]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[352ms]; status=[OK]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'incomingListener'
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/mobileapp/v1/put/user/profile.json]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[PUT]; servlet=[mvc]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[352ms]; status=[OK]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'incomingListener'
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@6427300a] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@47672d99] from thread [http-bio-8080-exec-3]
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
 24 Mar 2015 20:15:14 > org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

Comment: Is there any path through your object graph between `User` and `UserAndroid`?

Comment: Turn your logs to DEBUG, try again, and show us the results.

Comment: Which log you are referring to ?

Comment: The user entity has a foreign key reference to UserAndroid in 'user_id'

Comment: The Spring MVC logs.

Comment: Updated the logs in post.

Comment: Do you have Gson or Jackson on your classpath? What Spring version are you on? (Please add the logs to your question, don't make us go to another page.)

Comment: I suggest taking out the `fullContactDetails` association and debugging this request mapping to see which to see which of the argument resolvers are used for `@RequestBody UserAndroid user`, then putting the assoication back in and debugging again.

Comment: Updated.  I have both logs failed here: https://gist.github.com/madhur/ef357f614b18c6ed42cb
and success here:  https://gist.github.com/madhur/9660e8d87fe69bc89b4b

Comment: @MadhurAhuja looks like its `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`. Pop a breakpoint in there and see what happens -- ie. what makes that one return "no" when its being asked if it can support the argument resolution.

Comment: Breakpoint where? This is just a log

Comment: I think they mean debug Spring  by adding a breakpoint to the relevant method in `RequestResponseBodyMethod‌​Processor`.

Comment: @MadhurAhuja as Sotirios said - in the `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`.

Comment: Do I have to get the spring source code for this?  Right now, I am just using spring jars

Comment: Yeah, you would have to. With maven and a compatible IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ), the sources will be automatically downloaded.

Comment: Have you tried to replace method in annotation from PUT to POST?  It can be just hidden transparent proxy between your client and service, which forbids WebDAV methods like PUT/DELETE.  This is pretty common  for mobile networks.

Comment: There are various other PUT requests which are working

Comment: Not sure why you would need a `ModelMap model` in a REST API call (maybe I'm wrong), try removing `ModelMap model` and run it again. If it didn't work out, and if you're pretty sure that `@OneToOne(mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private FullContactDetails fullContactDetails;` is the cause of the problem, then try adding `@JsonIgnore` to the respective OneToOne mapping of the model class. Also do note about the causes of `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: Which version of jackson are you using? Also is it the codehaus or fasterxml one? Try using the fasterxml one if your are not already.

Comment: Can you please share your pom.xml, Need to see the json related dependencies? I had the same issue when using jersey REST services and although we had jackson on classpath we were missing <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
       <version>2.15</version> dependency

Comment: These are the jars in classpath : https://gist.github.com/madhur/d9ca3ed621df10adc802

Answer (score 2):

Please check the XML configuration where you have defined the contentnegotiating view resolver there you should have defined the mapping for json type media type . See if it works after updating those changes

This does not directly solves the issue but internally few dependencies resolve the mapping of content types for json as well try if it works

[Reference Link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/rest-spring)